# How can I know what device the file in /dev is mapped to

Tags: linux, dev

I have installed a new device in linux. 
If I enter lspci, i can see the information of this device.
But, I do not know which file in dev is mapped to this device.

Comment: `lspci` does not show you drivers.

Comment: What kind of device is it? The general class of device is a good place to start looking.

Comment: It is a scsi card and it connect to a tape driver

Answer (score 0):

Then use `lsscsi` instead - that should show you all the SCSI devices and what device file corresponds to each one.

Answer (score 0):

The *general* answer for any device is to run `dmesg` or check `/var/log/kern.log`.